Guy freeze his girlfriend till he find a cure for her.
In the 80s I saw a movie where a couple are in love, the girl had a disease and there was no cure to it, the boyfriend decides to froze his girlfriend until the cure is invented. After several years (I don't know how many exactly maybe 15 years) the man was reading a newspaper and he found that the cure was invented. When the girl is back to life the man is way older than her and she didn't recognize him at first, after several attempts she become familiar with the situation and she gets married with him.

@AnkitSharma Possibly, but it might not be the only movie with this plot, and that answer was never approved.

@Walt that's why not a straight close yet.

Could this be A Long Return (1975), also known as Largo Retorno?

Doctors tell David that his wife has less than days to live and he
desperately pleads with them for help of any kind. They inform him
that Anna's only chance of survival is to put her in a state of
perpetual deep cryogenic sedation, which would shut down her body
(stopping the disease from spreading), freeze her in time, and prevent
her from aging, until a cure can be found, in which event she would be
taken out of sedation. With great optimism, David accepts and Anna is
put in a state of cryogenic sedation.
For forty agonizing and heart aching years, David remains faithful to
Anna and waits for a cure to be found. Meanwhile, Anna's friends and
family move on with their lives, even as going as far as wanting to
pull the plug on her and bury her, as she remains sedated. A cure is
finally found in 2014, and she is successfully taken out of sedation
and fully cured. When Anna awakens she is kept at the hospital for
observations. She repeatedly asks to see her husband, not knowing he
is now middle aged and that she has been in sedation for the last
forty years. The doctor denies her request.




